# Expand width of textbox to left while typing with Bootstrap, js

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two text boxes side by side, one of which needs to expand its width to the left while a user types. When I try to expand the width, the right side grows, and I can't figure out to make the left side grow.

Answer (score 0):

Some example code would be usefull.

If you are using the grid system from bootstrap, you could manage to get what you are looking for using the offset columns.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
</div>
```

If you post some code, I would be able to give better advice.